# trivial firefox 6 question: seeing firebug, and how to see bookmarks as a panel along left hand side of window, like IE "Favorites"

Tags: firefox

In Firefox 6, the little firebug icon at the bottom right corner is moved ... is it gone?  Also, can you tell me how do I display my bookmarks along the edge of the window, so I can rapidly go through my bookmarks and click on them?  I just can't find this menu choice.  Thanks much, either answer is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent Firefox version, there is no longer a bar at the bottom of the screen. Firebug is now a button that you can add to the bars on top of the window, i.e. your nav bar.

[image]

As for the bookmarks, search for add-ons. I've not used it, but [All-in-One Sidebar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/all-in-one-sidebar/) looks promising for your intended use.

Comment: One can also do [cntrl-B](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/871294?s=show+bookmarks+sidebar&r=5&as=s) to show the bookmarks sidebar.  As far as I can tell, Mozilla removed the view->sidebar->bookmarks menu.

Comment: I did download the sidebar add-on I linked, and I do have to say that I like it a lot. It also includes history, downloads, extensions, and page info